# wglsharelists between same pixel formats except different multisampling

Tags: opengl

I did some modifications to a client's old OpenGL program and I was surprised to see wglsharelists being used to share lists between 2 contexts with different multisampling on them. Basically:

```
context1:=tcontext.create(multisample0x);
context2:=tcontext.create(multisample16x);
wglsharelists(context1,context2);
```

My understanding of wglsharelists was that it was only supposed to work on identical pixelformats, and those are not identical, each multisample_level having a different wglchoosepixelformatarb result.

So question is, what gives? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says "All rendering contexts of a shared display list must use an identical pixel format. Otherwise the results depend on the implementation of OpenGL used.". Is it that the OpenGL implementation of those machines just happened to support this or does wglsharelists generally work between pixel formats that would be otherwise identical except for their multisample_level?

edit: come to think of it, recently I installed a video game on my home computer, and I remember that when I went in the options and changed multisample_level, I could see the change happening live without having to reload textures for the different pixelformat. So, am I the last man on earth to find out this is standard?

Comment: Actually the pixelformat is not a property of OpenGL contexts. but of windows. Yes, when you create a OpenGL context you pass it a DC to configure it. But later on, you can perfectly rebind that context to other windows, as long as these are pixelformat *compatible* (compatible is the key word here). Multisampling is one of the parameters that can be freely be switched about, Color depth or non-/availability of depth or stencil buffer usually not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if you have a minute and dont mind, can you make an answer out of your comment and add a line about wglsharelists also working between such contexts, I'd accept that as answer, and it would be useful reference since I couldn't find this knowledge by asking internet search sites.

Answer (score 0):

#### This sounds like a task for Frame Buffer Objects, not window pixel formats.

Your problem, as I understand from your latest edit, is that you need a shared context to backup your OpenGL resources so that they survive changing the pixel format of your window. You can completely eliminate that if you draw into a multisampled FBO attachment and ignore the pixel format of the default framebuffer (window) altogether.

You would use `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` to copy (*resolve*, technically speaking) the anti-aliased results into your default framebuffer. This is vastly preferred over creating a window with a specific multisample pixel format these days because you can change the number of samples in your framebuffer on the fly and without ever touching any platform-specific constructs.

Comment: It's not something I need to do or anything like that, just something I saw during a contract that I didn't know could be done and had to ask, I used to think that wglsharelists would fail between 2 contexts that are identical except for different multisampling.

Comment: Anyway, back to your answer, I've never used glBlitFramebuffer, I'll look into it and try to add that knowledge to my toolkit, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Marladu: What I am discussing is explained in more detail [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling#Render-to-FBO). Again, since this is platform independent in OpenGL 3.0+ this is really the preferred way to approach multisampling.